# The tiles of the map are displaying incorrectly when hosted on a web server

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I've made an interactive map as a third party tool for a video game using the leaflet API. All is working fine on my computer, but when I push my project on my host, the map has some tiling errors.

[Here is what it looks like on local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nR1aB.jpg)

[Here is what it looks like on my host](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzlF0.jpg)

So i've stripped down my code to the bare minimum (no more markers, layerGroups...) and the bug persists.

Here is my code:

```
    <!doctype html>

<html>
<head>

  <title>PROJECT TITLE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
   crossorigin=""/>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>

</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div id="map" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background: #000000;"></div>
  <script>
  var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  });
  L.tileLayer('map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'SOMETHING SOMETHING',
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 5,
    tileSize: 256,
    noWrap: true
  }).addTo(map);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Got rid of the issue by setting bounds on my L.tileLayer.

Here is the new code:

```
    <!doctype html>

<html>
<head>

  <title>PROJECT TITLE</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css"
   integrity="sha512-xodZBNTC5n17Xt2atTPuE1HxjVMSvLVW9ocqUKLsCC5CXdbqCmblAshOMAS6/keqq/sMZMZ19scR4PsZChSR7A=="
   crossorigin=""/>
   <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"
   integrity="sha512-XQoYMqMTK8LvdxXYG3nZ448hOEQiglfqkJs1NOQV44cWnUrBc8PkAOcXy20w0vlaXaVUearIOBhiXZ5V3ynxwA=="
   crossorigin=""></script>

</head>
<body style="margin: 0;">
  <div id="map" style="width: 100vw; height: 100vh; background: #000000;"></div>
  <script>
  var bounds = [[-50, 50],[50, -50]];
  var map = L.map('map', {
    center: [0, 0],
    zoom: 2
  });
  L.tileLayer('map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    bounds: bounds,
    attribution: 'SOMETHING SOMETHING',
    minZoom: 2,
    maxZoom: 5,
    tileSize: 256,
    noWrap: true
  }).addTo(map);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

To find the correct values for the boundaries, I created a rectangle to try coordinates:

```
  var bounds = [[-50, 50],[50, -50]];
  L.rectangle(bounds, {
  color: "#ff7800",
  weight: 1
}).addTo(map);
```